# Populate TreeView with remote computer folders over TCP Client

Tags: tcp, treeview, tcpclient, populate

I want to make an Explorer to view folders from a remote computer using the `TcpClient`

Dose anyone have any solutions ?

The method i apropched is that on the server side i made that when i send the string "DirectoryInfo path" the server launches `DirectoryInfo mypath` returns the folders in a string and sends them back using NetworkStream, then i read the stream an add them to the treevies using a very raw and shitty method ex:

```
TreeNode hdd1 = new TreeNode(@"C:\");
string[] folder =Regex.Split("return string from netStream", "\r\n");
foreach (string fd in folder)
{
hdd1.Nodes.Add(fd);
}
treeView1.Nodes.Add(hdd1);
```

and that is how i get the first folders in "C:\", as you can see it is a primitive method, any ideas on how can i do this cleaner ? or how to get the next subfolders and so on, or at least improve my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Since all been so helpful, i managed to find a way.

I used a recursive method to add all directories on the remote PC  to a `TreeNode`
then i used the `BinaryFormatter` to serialize the node, and then used the `BinaryFormatter` to deserialize the node on my pc and add it to a `TreeView`.

Any other ways are welcomed to be shared here.